# How to make a table with formattable in R?

Tags: r, formattable

I'm trying to make a table in R with `formattable` but some rows are returning  `NA` and I don't know how to remove them.

In Excel the table looks like this, and this is how I would like it to be:

[image]

In `R` looks like this:

[image]

How can I make this table in `R` looks like in Excel?

Code:

```
library(readxl)
library(formattable)

indicadores <- read_excel("Dados/Tabela Indicadores.xlsx")

tabela_indicadores <- formattable(indicadores,
                                  align = c("c", "c", "c", "c"))
```

File that I'm using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CDhMkW7l78WEj45mYZ86LTY6PjCyhsSd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include your data as a data frame object in the question: use `dput(indicadores)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to replace the missing values with a character, "-" or "":

```
indicadores$Tema <- ifelse(is.na(indicadores$Tema), "-", indicadores$Tema)
tabela_indicadores <- formattable(indicadores, align = c("c", "c", "c", "c"))
```

I am assuming you do not want to exclude the lines completely. If you do want to remove them, use

```
tabela_indicadores <- formattable(na.omit(indicadores), align = c("c", "c", "c", "c"))
```

Comment: If I use ```na.omit``` some data will be missing. For example, in "Mobilidade e isolamento" I have four indicators and they will not appear with ```na.omit```.

Comment: I gave two answers because I was not sure which you wanted to do. The first changes the "NA" to a "-" or nothing ("") and the second removed the lines if that is what you wanted. Thanks for checking the answer. I've edited the answer to make the second option more clear.